# await async setInterval callback before advancing mock timer again

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, mocking, setinterval

I've found that attempting to test timers with Jest is hard enough without getting `async/await` involved.

I have a `setInterval` that's wrapped in a promise. The callback of the `setInterval` only resolves if the condition is matched for it to resolve *(shown below)*. If the promise is not resolved, it keeps attempting the iteration until it is.

`index.js`

```js
module.exports = async function() {
    let interval

    const _promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        interval = setInterval(async () => {
            try {
                const result = await asyncTask()

                if (result && result.val === 'Foo Bar') {
                    clearInterval(interval)
  
                    resolve(result)
                }
            } catch(err) {
                reject(err)
            }
        }, 10000) // 10 secs
    })
    const result = await _promise

    if (result) {
        return result
    }
}
```

I've mocked the return of `asyncTask` with something like:

`__mocks__/asyncTask.js`

```js
module.exports = jest.fn()
    .mockReturnValueOnce()
    .mockReturnValueOnce()
    .mockReturnValueOnce({
        val: 'Hello World'
    })
    .mockReturnValue({
        val: 'Foo Bar'
    })
```

What I am attempting to test is the callback of each iteration of the `setInterval` & I want to try to control that all operations in the callback are finished **before** I advance the timer again & the next `setInterval` happens. For example, *with the mock above*, a truthy result will be returned on the 3rd invocation of that function. The 4th invocation would also be a truthy result & would match the condition for the interval to be cleared & the promise to be resolved. 1 test I would look to do, *for example*, is have the `setInterval` iterate 3 times & even though `asyncTask` returns an object, the promise is not yet resolved. A few examples of how I've attempted this are below:

`index.test.js`

```
jest.useFakeTimers()

const _test = require('./index.js')

describe('test()', () => {
    test("Should call 'asyncTask' thrice (1)", () => {
        const promise1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            // I cannot await `_test()` here as the fast-forward of the timer would never happen
            // So I would actually have to wait 10 seconds
            _test().then(resolve)
        
            jest.advanceTimersByTime(10000)
        })
        const promise2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            _test().then(resolve)
            
            jest.advanceTimersByTime(10000)
        })
        const promise3 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            _test().then(resolve)
            
            jest.advanceTimersByTime(10000)
        })
        // I have to do it like this over a `Promise.all()` I imagine as I can't risk having them run in parallel
        // I imagine that has the potential to mess up the mock function call count of `asyncTask` so would not be reliable
        const result1 = await promise1
        const result2 = await promise2
        const result3 = await promise3

        expect(result1).toBeUndefined()
        expect(result2).toBeUndefined()
        expect(result3).toBeUndefined()
    })

    test('Should call `asyncTask` thrice (2)', async () => {
        _test().then(res => {
            expect(res).toBeInstanceOf(Object)
        })

        await jest.advanceTimersByTime(10000)
        await jest.advanceTimersByTime(10000)
        await jest.advanceTimersByTime(10000)
        await jest.advanceTimersByTime(10000)
    })
})
```

The latter was probably closer to what I want to achieve as in the former example; `promise1`, `promise2`, & `promise3` will never resolve so the test will never complete.

I can test this successfully is I use real timers *(`jest.useRealTimers()`)* instead of fake ones but the obvious issue is I would have to wait 40 secs for the promise to resolve & the test to complete.

Is there any clean way to achieve what I want here? Any help appreciated :)

Comment: First of all, wrapping async inside setInterval is an antipattern. A loop with awaiting a delay promise would be cleaner. It's unclear why you call `_test()` many times. If you test different conditions, they belong to separate tests. The problem with fake timers is likely that you need to wait a bit more before chaining a promise that was resolved with fake timer, `flush-promises` is commonly used for that.

Comment: @EstusFlask the main goal behind the test is the condition that the promise resolves on. In the code above, I want to test that `_test` will only get a resolved value on the 4th callback of `setInterval` as that will invoked `asyncTask` for the 4th time mocking a return value object with `val` being 'Foo Bar', on this condition, the promise (`_test()`) is resolved, that's what I'm trying to test. The condition on which the function is resolved. I will look into `flush-promises`. Thank you for your comment on the antipattern! I'll change that

Comment: I see, in this case it's better to move mockReturnValueOnce to the test that depends on them because otherwise this restricts a global mock to be used in a specific order.